# Show the percentage of the answer choices among all users

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table like this, with three fields:

```
User | Question# | Answer
```

The answer choices are only 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5

I need to write a SELECT statement such that it prints the percentage of the answers 1 and 2 together along with the percentage of the answers 3, 4 and 5 together.

The result should be like this:

```
Question# | %One+Two | %Three+Four+Five
1               %30          %70
2               %23          %77
.                .            .
.                .            .
.                .            .
```

I did this as an example to show the count of answers 1 and 2, but it doesn't provide what I need:

```
select QNum, Response, Count(Response)
 from SurveyResults
 group by QNum, Response
 having Response<3;
```

Comment: What database server are you using (MySQL? SQLServer?)?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter, because I was looking for the logic behind the answer. The syntax comes later, as you know SQL is standard with little differences among DB servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  QuestionNr
,       100.0 * count(case when Answer in (1,2) then 1 end) / count(*) as OneTwo
,       100.0 * count(case when Answer in (3,4,5) then 1 end) / count(*) as ThreeFourFive
from    YourTable
group by
        QuestionNr
```

Comment: it's a vague(ish) question but a pretty answer